# Postgresql : regexp_replace to remove special characters

Tags: postgresql

i need to remove all special character in PostgreSQL like this

```
' " , . / \ | ] [ { } & * - % ^ ! @ #
```

i try this

```
SELECT regexp_replace('Test.010. " @ $ %. تجربه', '[^\w\s\u0600-\u06FF]', ' ', 'g');
```

and result

```
Test 010
```

Arabic character removed !

i need to remove only special character only and leave or replace Arabic & English & number

Comment: I don't think regexp_replace is removing those character , as you can see postgresql returns those Arabic charters , see *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3ca2cdbb37ea5c242cb002e92e231f32)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use translate to convert those specific characters to spaces:

```
select translate('Test.010. " @ $ %. تجربه', '''",./\|][{}&*-%^!@#', '                   ');
        translate
--------------------------
 Test 010      $    تجربه
```

Comment: It's definitely available in postgres: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html